# Why ImageView Not appear image in my app?

Tags: java, android, picasso

i saved photo in server and show it in another place in my app but image doesn't appear in imageview and when i make log.e for url of image url was correct so i don't know why image not appear in imageview any help ????

```
public CustListMis(Activity context, ArrayList<String> NameArray, ArrayList<String> quantityArray, ArrayList<String> durationArray, ArrayList<String> dTimeArray, ArrayList<String> Images) {
    super(context, R.layout.temp_mis, quantityArray);
    this.context = context;
    this.NameArray = NameArray;
    this.quantityArray = quantityArray;
    this.durationArray = durationArray;
    this.dTimeArray=  dTimeArray;
    this.Images = Images;

}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.temp_mis, null, true);
    TextView name = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView quantity = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    TextView duration = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.duration);
    TextView dTime = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.dTime);
    ImageView myUploadImage = (ImageView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageyy);

    String url = Images.get(position);
   // String url = "http://sae-marketing.com/gamaia/PHOTOS/dream.age25@gmail.com-554806.png";
    Log.e("image",url);
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).noFade().resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(myUploadImage);


    name.setText(NameArray.get(position));
    quantity.setText(quantityArray.get(position));
    duration.setText(durationArray.get(position));
    dTime.setText(dTimeArray.get(position));


    return listViewItem;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried only that? `Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(myUploadImage);`. Does that works?

Comment: Did you tried to use `http://sae-marketing.com/gamaia/PHOTOS/dream.age25@gmail.com-554806.png` instead of url? (testing)

Comment: @shadowsheep Yes and doesn't work too

Comment: @Antonio yes i try it and it's work but when use load(url) and put link in string doesn't work

Comment: Can you paste your Logcat of the url? `Log.e("image",url);` what does it print out?

Comment: @shadowsheep yes when i run i open logcat and url appear in logcat and url was true

Comment: What do you mean with "and url was true"?

Comment: You're sure that variable **url** contains the URL you want?

Comment: @shadowsheep i code i put url of image which i was uploaded and when i mkae log.e("image",url); this url appear in logcat http://sae-marketing.com/gamaia/PHOTOS/dream.age25@gmail.com-554806.png"; it's it's same url which i upload image on it

Comment: @Antonio Yes 100%

Comment: If in logcat you see ` sae-marketing.com/gamaia/PHOTOS/…`  are u missing `http://` ?

Comment: If you enable log `Picasso.with(context).setLoggingEnabled(true)` what you see in logcat?

Comment: Your `context` variable is the activity containig the view?

Comment: @Antonio yes i miss it (http://)

Comment: So the problem is in your url variable ;)

Comment: Hope this solved your problem.

Comment: @Antoino @ shadowsheep thanks a lot i change string url to be string url = ("http://"+((Images.get(position))); and it's work thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. So choose your answer :)

Comment: Hi @MahmoudAhmed. Why didn't choose any answer? You can choose the answer you prefer. But as people take time to answer and help you, you should choose one of the propose answer. Moreover one of them is of one of the two guys that helped you find the solution.

Comment: @Cod3Flu3nc3 sorry u are right but answer which help me was in comment and i don't know how i choose a comment to be right answer

Comment: I've updated my question following our discussion. If you prefer to give a precedence to @Antonio ask him to write an answer and choose this one instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following OP comments we eventually ended up that the problem was really in the `String url` variable that does not contains a valid URL string (missing `http://`).

So the solution ended in doing that:

```
//String url = "http://sae-marketing.com/gamaia/PHOTOS/dream.age25@gmail.com-554806.png";
String url = "http://" + Images.get(position); 

ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(iv);
```

Comment: Its fine for me to choose this as the answer, +1.

Comment: Thanks @Antonio. Great interaction! Really appreciate and nice teamwork ;)

Answer (score 0):

ou can turn on Picasso logs using

```
Picasso.with(Context).setLoggingEnabled(true)
```

You will probably see an error message with a reason there